# Is knowledge singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

I am not sure if I should add an article. Should I use `a mean` or `means` or `a means`??

> Prior knowledge as means to combat ...

Or,

> Prior knowledge as a mean to combat ...

Or,

> Prior knowledge as a means to combat ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Knowledge* is uncountable, and so does not normally take either an indefinite article, or a plural ending. Like other uncountables, it can sometimes be used as countable, when it refers to a specific instance or a particular type (I mention this for completeness: it's not relevant in your example)

*Means* (in this sense) is singular, despite its *-s* ending. It can also be plural, so the article *a* is used when it is singular, not when it is plural.

Since *knowedge* is (uncountable and) singular, singular *means* is most appropriate here.

So the most idiomatic of your options is:

> Prior knowledge as a means to combat ...

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should use means, unless you're talking about the fact that there is just one possible way. Means show that there are multiple ways.
2. 3rd sentence sounds right. One reason would be that "a" refers to the fact that "prior knowledge" is one way to combat. For example, "Guns as a means to combat", 'a' shows how guns can be one way to combat.
3. I'm not sure whether 1st or 3rd is correct, I would say 3rd(?).

Comment: As Colin says, _means_ (in this sense) ends in 's' whether it's singular or plural.